# Is there a way of getting values of properties in an action class without supplying them as query-string parameters while using a redirect action?

Tags: java, struts2, query-string, querystringparameter

When a `POST` request succeeds, the request is redirected as follows.

```
private String message; //Getter and setter.

//Required validators.
@Action(value = "AddUpadteCategory",
    results = {
        @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Category", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "status", "${status}"}),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Category.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs={
        @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "catId, catName, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
    })
public String insertOrUpdate()
{
    if(true)  //Some conditional check.
    {
         setMessage(getText("message.key.true"));
    }
    else
    {
          setMessage(getText("message.key.false"));
    }

    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

This message is supplied as a query-string parameter, if no validation/conversion errors occur.

Sometimes, this message could be long forming a long URL string.

Is there a way to get this message without passing it as a query-string parameter, while using a redirect action?

<sub>Storing this message into a session could not be an alternative.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `store interceptor` and set its `operationMode` parameter on `AUTOMATIC` as follows:

```xml
<action name="actionName" class="..." method="...">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result ..../>
</action>
```

It will automatically set your messages in appropriate scope. For `redirectAction` result it will be session scope but after displaying your messages this interceptor will automatically remove them.

EDIT (Annotation syntax):

```
 interceptorRefs={
        @InterceptorRef(value="store", params={"operationMode", "AUTOMATIC"}),
        @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "catId, catName, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
    })
```

Comment: Regarding annotations, it seems it requires class level configurations.

Comment: One additional thing, please : Is it possible to store only those messages which we explicitly add through the `addActionMessage()` , `addActionError()` methods (or is it possible to remove specific messages)? (In my case, I always have an error message that appears through out the application. The message is about a security token which is required to be passed as a hidden field but I don't have setters/getters for this field simply because they don't require. the hidden field is directly passed to a security framework - Spring  and not Struts).

Comment: ...This always leaves a message quite unnecessarily like `Error setting expression '_csrf' with value 'xxx'` which I always get while using `<s:actionmessage/>` on a JSP page **in addition to my own message**. (Of course, if `struts.devMode` is set to false then, this message doesn't appear but it requires to be on until the development is finished).

Comment: For that case, use `params` interceptor and set the name of this token field in `excludeParams` parameter.

Comment: Excluding this parameter through `excludeParams` does not work because that parameter does not have a corresponding mutator and an accessor in the corresponding action class simply because they are not required. (why do we unnecessarily have setters and getters for parameters which we are not going to use in the action class?).